# Laravel eloquent query and join on OR condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do an eloquent query where it joins on a table where column `a = x` `OR` column `b = x`; and I cannot get it to work. So I am hoping that someone can help.

Here is my query:

```
$candidates = HrCandidate::where('people_id', '<>', 'NULL')

  ->with('contact')

  ->join(

    'people',

    ->where('id','people_id')

    ->orWhere('alternate_id','people_id')

  )

  ->get();
```

I am trying to join with the people table but where `people_id = 1` or the `alternate_id` column.  So I am hoping someone can help with this.

Comment: You should look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins under Advanced Joins.

Answer (score 2):

To get started, pass a Closure as the second argument into the join method. The Closure will receive a JoinClause object which allows you to specify constraints on the join clause:

```
$candidates = HrCandidate::join('people', function ($join) {
        $join
            ->on('people.id', '=', 'candidates.people_id')
            ->orOn('people.alternate_id', '=', 'candidates.people_id');
    })
    ->where('people_id', '<>', 'NULL')
    ->get();
```